# Xcode copy from mac to laptop shows error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm primarily developing on my MAC, sometimes I take my project files on a USB-Stick on the go with my macbook, so I can work on things while not at home.

It worked fine so far until now, I'm getting a bunch of Semantic errors, saying that:

```
"editSetting.settingAnimateSelection = @NO;"
```

Error: "Property 'editSetting.settingAnimateSelection' not found on object of type 'Setting *'

settingAnimateSelection as well as 2 other items I added to my CoreData structure, I generated the NSManagedSubclass on my mac when I added them, they are declared/defined in the

```
setting.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * settingAnimateSelection;
```

also in the

```
setting.m
@dynamic settingAnimateSelection;
```

along with a whole bunch of other attributes, there are no relationships.
Everything works on my iMAC, but as soon as I copy my project folder onto my MacBook,
it won't run anymore and shows all those Semantic Errors telling me it can't find them.

I did CLEAN already and tried deleting my app from the simulator and my phone, but nothing helps.

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi there. This is not an answer. But you really ought to consider using a versioning system. I am not working for Atlassian but we use their solutions at work. And you could just setup for a free 5 seat repo on their Bitbucket service, assuming that you have Internet connection both at work and home. Then you would not have to move stuff around manually :) You can even use a UI client like Source Tree in case you don't want to use commandline git. Best regards Lasse

Comment: If an answer work for you, you may wan to tick *This answer is useful* to let others know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: You may have multiple instances of like-named files in your source tree. Search for those and delete duplicates from the Xcode project (and possibly tree as well).

**Reason**: There is a pitfall when re-generating your NSManagedSubclass files...

It is likely (common) that the new generated files (like `setting.h` and co.) do not go in the very same directory as the old ones. These can easily end up in a nested directory, or have been moved to a different location by the user.

If so, you have multiple versions of source files with the same name in your source tree.

Oddly enough, the one given source file you readily open with the UI is not necessarily the one that the compiler finds.

**How to avoid the NSManagedSubclass pitfall**:

Xcode > Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass... > Select the data models with entities you would like to manage > navigate to the dest directory (you should see your old files) > [Create]

You should get the warning: **The following files already exist and will be replaced:...**

**Additional Notes**:

1. Make sure you are selecting the correct **Target>Device>OS**. If often resets upon opening on a new Xcode.
2. +1 for the repository suggestion. You can use git or svn locally. It would have little or no effect on the problem at hand, though.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion.
I already checked target and all the build settings, it's all the same. That's not the issue....
any other ideas?

Comment: Have your tried **"Clean Build Folder..."** option-shift-command-K? What about **"Delete Derived Data"** Xcode>Window>Organizer>Projects>Derived Data [Delete...]

Comment: Yes I tried both, still have 11 semantic issues. Totally clueless why that is. Are there any other directories or temporary files I could delete?

Comment: Got it! When you re-generated your NSManagedSubclass files, it is likely that the new `setting.h` did not go in the very same directory as the old one. On the original Xcode project, your project builds and links to the correct files (even though you may have 2 sets). But when you open the same project on a different machine, Xcode is confused and may build with the old `setting.h`, not the new one. The `setting.h` you are looking at in the editor is not actually the `setting.h` the compiler finds.

Comment: Thank you so much @gothic dev, that was the issue. For some reason there were duplicates of my setting.h and setting.m in my project directory. I remember that at some point I moved files around and organized my project from within Xcode (making new folders etc...) and for some reason I ended up with duplicates, if Xcode generated copies and kept the original when I moved the files, or if I regenerated them and had the output go into a new directory. Not sure, but that was what solved my issue.
Thank you again solo much for taking the time and investigating, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a hosted version control system. Then do checkouts, commits and merges.

By default new projects get a local repository, local to the project. Your other options are to stop using local repositories or to save a Snapshot, export the Snapshot from the Organizer and then share that snapshot to your other machine.

By far, hosted repositories are the least trouble in the long run.